# select incremental value within a link and assign to a var

Tags: jquery, html, css

In my dynamical app, it will appends few links and assign id (using var num) for some purpose. The var num is incremental, like a tab - tab 1, tab 2 and so on.. I

I have to declare the variable (num) in few function, so it's out of scope if I want to reuse them.

so I thought of retrieve one more time by looking into this element :

```
"<a href='#" + num + "</a>"
```

no idea what selector to use to get the num..

Comment: No idea what you are asking, please reword your question.

Comment: I think You have not provided correct information. provide actual "<a href='#" + num + "</a>" which You are getting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var num = $('a').attr('href').replace('#', '');
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand you correctly but you can always return the variable (num) from function to void the out of scope issue and also not lose the value of num.